# Map returns null when getting value based on key name

Tags: jenkins, groovy, key-value, linkedhashmap

I have a very strange problem regarding getting values from LinkedHashMap in Grovvy when running in Jenkins pipeline.

I have a map like this: `map = ['key1': 'param1']`

Now I want to get a value of key1, so I call `map.get('key1')` or `map['key1']`. Surprisingly both of these return `null`.

When I try to call `map.keySet()`, it returns `key1`. And most interestingly, when I call `map.get(map.keySet()[0])` it return `param1` as expected.

So how is it possible that the direct `map.get('key1')` doesn't work?

**UPDATE:**

After some investigation, I have found out that the `key1` is not a String but `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl`. Does anybody have any idea why it was casted to this class and not String?

This is how the initial map is created:

```
result = ["${key}": value]
```

Comment: Are you using GString? http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes

Comment: I have tried all mentioned commands in the online Groovy console and it works indeed, but it still doesn't work in the Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: @Jayan Your comment made me check the key class. Check my update, please.

Comment: I guess your original question in answered, but your edit now has another question.  Please ask that separate question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GStrings (groovy.lang.GString) which are also called interpolated strings in other programming languages.  `"${key}"` is  a GString,  but `"${key}".toString()` is a String. More detail at [here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Following approach can resolve your issue

```
def key = 'key1'
def a = "${key}"  // or a = "${key}".toString()
def result = [:]
result[a] = 'param1'
println result.key1 // or result['key1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code does work.

```
map = ['key1': 'param1']
assert 'param1' == map['key1']
```

**After the update in Question**

The key was actually not a String.  `toString()` will give to you string as `String`, that can be used as key

Comment: It works for me in online Groovy console, but in the Jenkins pipeline, it still returns `null` for some reason.